# Update list via AJAX when uploading a file

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I have a problem. When a user uploads a file it goes in a filesystem and the filename is being uploaded in DB. After uploading the file, the user should see in a list all his filenames including the new uploaded file. All this should be done without reloading the page. I got everything fine except this auto refresh list. I'm using Laravel and Dropzone.js. This is the route

```
Route::get('/', function () {

return View::make('index')->with('files', DB::table('files')->select('filename')->get()) });
```

And here I loop all the results

```
@foreach($files as $file)
    <li>{{ $file->filename }}</li>
@endforeach
```

And the problem as I said is updating the list with the new uploaded name withould refreshing the page

Answer (score 0):

After uploading a file, you need to append a new `<li>` to your list with the new filename.